# Where is my iframe in the published web application/sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I've been running into various errors when trying to control the `window` in DOM of my published web app and addon sidebar.

- `window.location` returns a vague  unknown url like `n-rysutduudd.google-usercontent.com` instead of my published web app url `script.google.com/[SCRIPT_ID]/exec`
- Attempts to redirect my published web-app to a new url fails
  `window.location.href=www.google.com`
- Forms in web app, when submitted  redirects to blank page.

After researching, I figured  this is due to the web content being served in a iframe. The documentation doesn't show much except that the webapp is sandboxed in a iframe.

Relevant documentation I've researched:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions

Some of the relevant questions I've looked into:

- [window.location.href = window.location.href returning a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488018)
- [Google script web app goes blank page after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293936)
- [How to stop redirected URL from being masked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685553)

My **specific** question is: Where exactly is my iframe window in the published web app or my add on sidebar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
              PUBLISHED WEB APP
+---------------------------------------------+
|              script.google.com              |
|                                             |<------- [#0] window.top The top frame
|                                             |
|     +---------------------------------+     |
|     |     *.googleusercontent.com     |<----+-------- [#1] Outer Sandboxed Iframe
|     |         sandboxFrame            |     |
|     |    +-----------------------+    |     |
|     |    |        /blank         |    |     |
|     |    |    userHtmlFrame      |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    |     Where the html    |<---+-----+-------- [#2] Inner Sandboxed Iframe
|     |    |    file you created   |    |     |
|     |    |       is loaded       |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    |                       |    |     |
|     |    +-----------------------+    |     |
|     |                                 |     |
|     |                                 |     |
|     +---------------------------------+     |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

You're right. Most of the errors are due to  the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) sandboxing done by Google. To answer your question,

- Your window is located in a iframe with id: `userHtmlFrame` with  it's `src` set to `/blank`.
- This frame is nested inside another frame with `src`: `*.googleusercontent.com` and id `sandboxFrame`.
- Finally, The `sandboxFrame` is nested inside the main frame: `script.google.com`

#### Notes:

- `window` in your  published app refers to the inner most frame.
- This inner most frame has it's own [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and most other attributes unique to a window.
- Unfortunately, this inner frame cannot be navigated elsewhere.
- All window navigation must be done on the outermost frame: `script.google.com`.  This is why the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#setting_the_link_target_attribute) asks you to set [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) or [anchor's `target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) to the `top` frame.
- Forms  without [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes) are submitted to the inner frame `/blank`. Therefore, you're redirected to a blank page. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe#form_submission_are_no_longer_prevented_by_default) states,

> With IFRAME mode however HTML forms are allowed to submit, and if a form element has no action attribute specified it will submit to a blank page. Worse, the inner iframe will redirect to the blank page before the onclick handler has a chance to finish.

> The solution is to add JavaScript code to your page that prevents the form elements from actually submitting, so that the click handlers have time to function

- The [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin) of your iframe `userHtmlFrame` is [inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin) from `sandboxFrame` and set to `*.googleusercontent.com`. For all intents and purposes([cors](/questions/tagged/cors), whitelisting origins, [fetch](/questions/tagged/fetch) requests), this is the  effective `origin`.
- The `sandboxFrame` currently has the [following  feature policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes): `allow`

`accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *`

- Currently, It has the following [sandbox attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes), which limit what you can  do to other frames:

`allow-downloads allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation`

- The outer windows/other windows can be  referenced using `window.top` or `window.parent` or `window.opener` from the inner frame. But, There are multiple restrictions imposed due to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access). Cross origin access is limited mostly. Of particular note would be the `window.postMessage`, which allows communication between frames.

---

```
            SIDEBAR/MODAL DIALOG
+---------------------------------------------+
|              docs.google.com                |
|  +--------------------------------------+   |<------- [#0] window.top The top frame
|  |      /macros/.../iframedAppPanel     |<--+-------- [#1] Frame1 Same origin 
|  |  +---------------------------------+ |   |
|  |  |     *.googleusercontent.com     |<|---+-------- [#2] Outer Sandboxed Iframe
|  |  |         sandboxFrame            | |   |
|  |  |    +-----------------------+    | |   |
|  |  |    |        /blank         |    | |   |
|  |  |    |    userHtmlFrame      |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |     Where the html    |<---+-|---+-------- [#3] Inner Sandboxed Iframe
|  |  |    |    file you created   |    | |   |
|  |  |    |       is loaded       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    |                       |    | |   |
|  |  |    +-----------------------+    | |   |
|  |  |                                 | |   |
|  |  |                                 | |   |
|  |  +---------------------------------+ |   |
|  |                                      |   |
|  +--------------------------------------+   |
|                                             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

All the above notes for web app stands true also for webcontent published using HtmlService in sidebar or modal dialogs. However,

- There is a extra nested layer of iframe here.
- The `allow-top-navigation` is  missing from the sandbox attributes. Therefore, It is not possible to change/navigate the top frame(`docs.google.com`) here.

---

#### Changelog:

- [Sep 1, 2021](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#september_1_2021): `allow-top-navigation` is removed and `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation` is added instead. Security  for the end user is increased at the cost of convenience for the developers.