# How to access camera from google apps script webapp framed in a cross origin site?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a iframe on my page. The iframe src is a google webapp with src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/.......".

That page is a form and it works with camera and geolocalisation.
My problem is, when I directly access the form without framing, it works perfectly, but when I frame the apps script web app, the form works but camera and geo doesn't.

I mean: if I use https://script.google.com/macros/s/.... the form works perfect!
but if I use iframe on my web page, the camera and geo no work!
`<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/......."></iframe>`
I tried adding `allow="camera; microphone` and another attributes but still no work it.

How can I solve that?

here my link
iframe:
iframe allow="camera *; microphone *"  src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsaOlh4Gp2EJmdyQ9cvkYmezTCsg_9wd6ILjdwTe6MRgNBDitcE5Hijr2sNeBknMvp/exec" width="750" height="1100" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="cultos" name="cultos">/iframe

link script
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsaOlh4Gp2EJmdyQ9cvkYmezTCsg_9wd6ILjdwTe6MRgNBDitcE5Hijr2sNeBknMvp/exec
note: link script work 100% but on iframe no work camera and geolocalitation

Comment: Any error/debug logs on the browser console or devtools?

Comment: nope, just GET https://xxxxx/favicon.ico 404, no icon

Comment: the form work pefect on url script and iframe, but camera and geo no work on iframe

Comment: i have this errors Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/wardeninit?_reqid=80444&rt=j' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: and this 1453801117-warden_bin_i18n_warden__es.js:157 POST https://script.google.com/wardeninit?_reqid=80444&rt=j net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: and this GET https://doc-0g-4s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ri901ootvh9vqrdlem0ab6clgjrlk8sb/va4tnln0iirune7rrd7g37tt5paedksc/1633478475000/14314017474793383625/14314017474793383625/13Fg8mnNtiwN_98G6e3seAIkHQH1MaA7-?e=download&authuser=0 403

Answer (score 2):

Since Google apps script web app is a [nested iframe with different origins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551838), you might need to add a specific [`allowlist` along with `allow`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy#the_iframe_allow_attribute). This is because the default `allow`'s `allowlist` defaults to `src`. Thus it won't allow nested cross origin iframes. Try

```html
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/......." 
        allow="camera https://[SCRIPT_ID].googleusercontent.com"></iframe>
```

Here, `SCRIPT_ID` can be found by examining the "#1 Outer sandbox iframe" html structure according to  the structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551838). Alternatively and less securely,  you can allow all origins using `*`,

```html
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/......." 
        allow="camera *"></iframe>
```

Comment: thx ill test it,

Comment: @AsambleaCristiana Did it work? adding a ``*``work?(``allow="camera *"``)

Comment: nope, here my link if u can help me! thx for ever!, https://asambleacristianamendoza.com/index.php/inscripciones-maipu/ here is embeb code  <iframe allow="camera *; microphone *"  src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsaOlh4Gp2EJmdyQ9cvkYmezTCsg_9wd6ILjdwTe6MRgNBDitcE5Hijr2sNeBknMvp/exec" width="750" height="1100" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe> AND this my link to apps https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsaOlh4Gp2EJmdyQ9cvkYmezTCsg_9wd6ILjdwTe6MRgNBDitcE5Hijr2sNeBknMvp/exec

Comment: if u use url link work 100%!, but if u use throught iframe no work camera and geolocalitation

Comment: @AsambleaCristiana Is this in chrome?

Comment: yes ... but on my mobile phone it doesn't work either

Comment: try u to fill form in both and tell me, ill check it