# How to implement fullStory with Google Sheet Apps Script Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, fullstory

I am new to **Google Apps Script Add-on**. I want to implement **fullStory** for data capture
and user experience. I had developed the **fullstory** in the **excel add-in** successfully, but when I tried to create the same for the **google app script add-on** it was not working.
I have added the **script** tag in google sheet add-on but it's not working as per it's **document**.

I have followed the below step:

https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020828273-Getting-Started-with-FullStory

I have added the below script in head section of add-on HTML file.

```
<script>
window['_fs_host'] = 'fullstory.com';
window['_fs_script'] = 'edge.fullstory.com/s/fs.js';
window['_fs_org'] = 'id';
window['_fs_namespace'] = 'FS';
(function(m,n,e,t,l,o,g,y){
    if (e in m) {if(m.console && m.console.log) { m.console.log('FullStory namespace conflict. Please set window["_fs_namespace"].');} return;}
    g=m[e]=function(a,b,s){g.q?g.q.push([a,b,s]):g._api(a,b,s);};g.q=[];
    o=n.createElement(t);o.async=1;o.crossOrigin='anonymous';o.src='https://'+_fs_script;
    y=n.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(o,y);
    g.identify=function(i,v,s){g(l,{uid:i},s);if(v)g(l,v,s)};g.setUserVars=function(v,s){g(l,v,s)};g.event=function(i,v,s){g('event',{n:i,p:v},s)};
    g.anonymize=function(){g.identify(!!0)};
    g.shutdown=function(){g("rec",!1)};g.restart=function(){g("rec",!0)};
    g.log = function(a,b){g("log",[a,b])};
    g.consent=function(a){g("consent",!arguments.length||a)};
    g.identifyAccount=function(i,v){o='account';v=v||{};v.acctId=i;g(o,v)};
    g.clearUserCookie=function(){};
    g.setVars=function(n, p){g('setVars',[n,p]);};
    g._w={};y='XMLHttpRequest';g._w[y]=m[y];y='fetch';g._w[y]=m[y];
    if(m[y])m[y]=function(){return g._w[y].apply(this,arguments)};
    g._v="1.3.0";
})(window,document,window['_fs_namespace'],'script','user');
</script>
```

Code of Apps Script

**Login.html**

```html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@fluentui/web-components"></script>
  <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
  <!-- Style CDN -->
  <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/graphik" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window['_fs_host'] = 'fullstory.com';
    window['_fs_script'] = 'edge.fullstory.com/s/fs.js';
    window['_fs_org'] = 'id';
    window['_fs_namespace'] = 'FS';
    (function (m, n, e, t, l, o, g, y) {
      if (e in m) { if (m.console && m.console.log) { m.console.log('FullStory namespace conflict. Please set window["_fs_namespace"].'); } return; }
      g = m[e] = function (a, b, s) { g.q ? g.q.push([a, b, s]) : g._api(a, b, s); }; g.q = [];
      o = n.createElement(t); o.async = 1; o.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; o.src = 'https://' + _fs_script;
      y = n.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; y.parentNode.insertBefore(o, y);
      g.identify = function (i, v, s) { g(l, { uid: i }, s); if (v) g(l, v, s) }; g.setUserVars = function (v, s) { g(l, v, s) }; g.event = function (i, v, s) { g('event', { n: i, p: v }, s) };
      g.anonymize = function () { g.identify(!!0) };
      g.shutdown = function () { g("rec", !1) }; g.restart = function () { g("rec", !0) };
      g.log = function (a, b) { g("log", [a, b]) };
      g.consent = function (a) { g("consent", !arguments.length || a) };
      g.identifyAccount = function (i, v) { o = 'account'; v = v || {}; v.acctId = i; g(o, v) };
      g.clearUserCookie = function () { };
      g.setVars = function (n, p) { g('setVars', [n, p]); };
      g._w = {}; y = 'XMLHttpRequest'; g._w[y] = m[y]; y = 'fetch'; g._w[y] = m[y];
      if (m[y]) m[y] = function () { return g._w[y].apply(this, arguments) };
      g._v = "1.3.0";
    })(window, document, window['_fs_namespace'], 'script', 'user');
  </script>
</head>
```

**macro.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('home');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('login').evaluate().setTitle("Add-on")
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}
```

I have provided the image of network pane for fullStory.
[image: network pane of fullStory]

Image of privacy Section
[image: Privacy section]
Here is the link for fullStory document.

https://developer.fullstory.com/introduction

I don't know why it's not working.
Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Pleae show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts including links to the most relevant posts from this site explaning why they didn't help you.

Comment: I have added the script tag in the head section of the HTML file of the add-on. I had find the document for fullStory development for the google add-on but I'm not got it.
I had find the question on the StackOverflow  but i failed to get it.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (you should include how the add-on opens the html and a complete html, not only the script of the head)

Comment: Also add the relevant Web Browser JavaScript console logs errors and the Apps Script execution logs

Comment: There is not any console logs error. In the network pane, it's showing the status 200.
Fullstory working fine with other web project but not with add-on

Comment: Could you explain "not working"? What do you expect to happen? Why? What happened?

Comment: When I see users of the day in my fullStory account. At that time it displays 0 Users.

Comment: I have tried the same code with another web project. In that project, it's working fine. In my fullStory account it's not displaying user of the day

Comment: What about "Privacy" section in fuStory dashboard - can you see multiple data elements?

Comment: I have added the screenShot of the privacy section.

Answer (score 1):

Your client side of the sidebar is sent as a string to be injected into an iframe.
One thing that you could try that others have found worked for them is adding this additional flag in script:

window['_fs_is_outer_script'] = true;

You can get more information on this flag in the [iframe article](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020622514-Can-FullStory-capture-content-that-is-presented-in-iframes-#h_01F1G33B40Q2TPQA8MA7SF8Y5P) :

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with fullstory, but I see that your add-on is opening the client-side code in a sidebar. In this case the client-side of the sidebar is sent as as string to be  injected into an iframe, so it will be constrained to the sidebar dimensions.

In other other words, if you are intending to use fullstory over the grid and other Google Sheets UI elements, it will not work.

Anyway, please be aware that the client-side code is satinized so the parts that don't pass the sanitization will not be included, so use the browser developer tools to validate that the whole client-side code is sent.

P.S. I suggest you to include `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>`, `</html>`.

Related

- [Where is my iframe in the published web application/sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63551837/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Comment: docType already added in the original code. I have not include the question.

Comment: Measns we can't implement fullStory in the google Appscript Add-on?

Comment: I added a link to a related question that you might find helpful to understand the iframe layers in the sidebar. As I mentioned in my answer I'm not familiar with fullStory, if no body else comes with a more specific answer you have to read the fullStory docs to learn about its requirements / limitations.

Comment: Your related link help to understand the layers. but i'm not getting the meaning of

"In other words, if you are intending to use fullstory over the grid, it will not work."

which type of grid you are talking about?

Comment: Have you hear the term "gridlines"? Like in Sheets toolbar  View > Show > Gridlines

Comment: The grid is the area where the cells are placed. A sheet contains a grid (cells organized in columns and rows), column headers, row headers,, a tab, etc.