# Chrome notifications using Javascript within Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-applications, notifications

I'm trying to use javascript from within a Google Apps Script project in order to display notifications to the user using chrome.notifications

However, this isn't working. Whenever I query Notification.permission it returns 'denied', even if I explicitly 'allow' in settings for the page:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("notifications").evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

}
```

notifications.html

```
<script>

let permission = Notification.permission;
alert(permission);

</script>
```

...always returns 'denied'.

I use HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile to create the HTML pages in my project, so I suspect this issue is happening because Chrome doesn't allow notifications from within a cross-origin frame.

I was wondering if anyone had come up with a solution or work-around for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve]. You should include the doGet function and show the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben, I've updated my original post with the doGet and code

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification. Then, try to fix the code. If you get stuck, [edit] the question about what you found unclear about the link or how to implement something like the example in Google Apps Script's HTML file.

Comment: `explicitly 'allow' in settings for the page:` Could you show which url/domain you allowed the permission for? Is it `script.google.com` or `n****.googleusercontent.com`?

Comment: @themaster It's for script.google.com - even if I set the 'Notifications' permission for that domain to 'Allow', the above code still returns 'denied'?

Comment: [The iframe origin is ``****.googleusercontent.com``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/). Unless you're able to set it to "allow" for that origin, it's pointless. Also, [you can't "ask" for permission from a cross origin frame](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6451284559265792). So, if this becomes a public app, the end users have to follow whatever technique you used to "allow" notification, if there's even a technique that makes it possible.

Comment: Ok thanks @TheMaster - at least I now know why this is happening, thanks for the info.