# Sending message from iframe to parent window and then to a second iframe to reload using Appscript WebApp

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, google-sheets-api

I have a main html, with iframe1 and iframe2 inside. I want to send a message to iframe2 to reload itself after a button has been pressed in iframe1. Message arrives successfully as can be seen in the console log, but is not refreshing the iframe2. Even when I manually right click and reload iframe2, the iframe2 turns to a blank screen. I am using Appscript Webapp for iframe1 and iframe2 and it is pulling data from Google Sheets.

Main Html:

```html
        <script>
        // Function to refresh the second iframe
        function refreshSecondIframe() {
            var iframe2 = document.getElementById('iframe2');
            console.log("Sending message to iframe2");
            iframe2.contentWindow.postMessage('refreshIframe', 'https://example.com');  // Update the domain to match your actual domain
        }
    
        // Event listener to handle postMessage from iframe1
        window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log("Received message in main HTML document:", event);
    
            // Check data before taking action
            if (event.data === 'buscarButtonClicked') {
                refreshSecondIframe();
            }
        });
         </script>
```

iframe1 HTML

```html
    <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="submitFormAndNotifyParent()" style="grid-column: span 2; margin-top: 10px;">

    <script>
        function submitFormAndNotifyParent() {
            if (window.parent !== window.top) {
                console.log("Sending message from iframe1 to parent window");
                window.top.postMessage("buscarButtonClicked", 'https://example.com');
            }
            submitForm() 
        }
    </script>
```

iframe2 HTML

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log("Received message in iframe2:", event);

        // Check data before taking action
        if (event.data === 'refreshIframe') {
            console.log("Refreshing iframe2");

            // Use the following line to forcefully reload the iframe
            document.location.href = document.location.href;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The site where I am running this and you can see the logs is [www.example.com/b*emphasized](http://www.example.com/b*emphasized) text*.
Please if my question is not well written, give me some advice on how to make it better instead of bad rep :).

Comment: Try `window.parent.parent.location.reload()`. If that doesn't work, you need to force the reload from `main.html`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-

Comment: I believe this comes from a step back. Apparently the message is being sent from iframe1 to main html, received and sent from main html to iframe2 but not being received in iframe2. I believe because of cross origin conflict. Any idea on how can main html send the message to iframe2? Its weird beause iframe1 is succesfully sending and receving message in main html.

Comment: Besides this, when I manually reload iframe2 by right clicking on it, the frame just turns into a blank page. Not sure why this happens?

Comment: The link above  clarifies why the blank page happens. Regarding `because of cross origin conflict`, I don't think so. `window.postMessage()` doesn't have cross  origin restrictions.