# How do I properly deploy a web app from Google Sheets App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

I am trying to make an online web app for my employees to help them with their mixing and loading process of a herbicide. It requires dilution as the temperature outside rises, so the goal is to have them input a temperature and the volume currently in their tank and return how much they need to add. I am very new to deployments and my doGet() function seems to be working, but the result is a blank white page.
Here's the code:

```
var high_max_temp = 22; //Celsius
var mid_max_temp = 28; //Celsius
var tankSize = 200; //Gallons
var maxFiesta = 30; //Liters
var maxActivate = 10; //Liters
var fiestaRatio = tankSize/maxFiesta; //30L for a full tank, full strength
var activateRatio = tankSize/maxActivate; //10L for a full tank, full strength
var midStrengthMultiplier = 0.75; //75% Strength
var lowStrengthMultiplier = 0.3; //30% Strength

function doGet(e) {
  var result = '';
  if (e.parameter.temperature && e.parameter.volume) {
    var temperature = parseFloat(e.parameter.temperature);
    var volume = parseFloat(e.parameter.volume);
    Logger.log('Temperature: ' + temperature + ', Volume: ' + volume);
    var fiestaValue = fiestaDilutionCalculator(volume, temperature);
    Logger.log('Fiesta Value: ' + fiestaValue);
    result = '<h1>Result:</h1><p>Fiesta Dilution Value: ' + fiestaValue.toFixed(2) + '</p>';
  } else {
    result = '<h1>Fiesta Dilution Calculator</h1>' +
             '<form>' +
             '  Temperature (°C): <input type="text" name="temperature"><br>' +
             '  Volume (mL): <input type="text" name="volume"><br>' +
             '  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">' +
             '</form>';
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result);
}

//Calculates the required fiesta depending on tank volume and temperature
function fiestaDilutionCalculator(volume,temp) {
  
  //get strength based on temperature
  var strength = 1;
  if (temp <= high_max_temp){
    strength = 1;
  }
  else if(temp > high_max_temp && temp <= mid_max_temp){
    strength = midStrengthMultiplier;
  }
  else if(temp > mid_max_temp){
    strength = lowStrengthMultiplier;
  }
  
  var fiestaValue = ((tankSize-volume)/tankSize)*(maxFiesta*strength);

  Logger.log(fiestaValue);
  return fiestaValue;
}
```

At the top, I have my variables followed by my doGet() function. Below is the function that does the calculations which is producing the correct values. When I hit my submit button, the screen is white and the 'result' does not appear. Is there something I'm missing in the back end or is my code just improper?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not provided a [mcve] and your question is too broad

Comment: Do you see the big blue button that says deploy in the script editor.  Thats how you deploy the webapp.  But really you question is simply my webapp doesn't work can we fix it for you and that's too broad because we cannot reproduce the problem easily.

Comment: Forms need  `preventDefault` (and `action` attribute or `google.script.run`) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-i