Integrate Phone Authentication feature of firebase with google appscript - web app
I managed to integrate google sign in feature of firebase with my appscript web app. But I can't seem to figure out how to integrate phone authentication. I seem to be getting 'Hostname match not found' error. I did a bit of research on my own but found no solutions for the same, besides other people facing the same issue such as What to put as 'Authorized Domain' under Firebase authentication for a single page Google App Script webapp
Has anyone figured this out yet? would be nice to know if this is even possible or not
I have crosschecked the firebase config files of my Index.html, they all match.

The domain would be window.location of the innermost html. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-published-web-application-sidebar

Not sure if I understood, how should I go about finding this?

I figured it out!! Thanks a tonne for sharing that link, it really helped!

The authorized domain would be the innermost iframe  windows location. See structure of a Google apps script webapp in my answer here. You can figure out this domain location by loading your webapp and inspecting the iframe src in the html or executing window.location in the developer console, after selecting to execute it in the context of the innermost iframe.

Yes, this is exactly what I did. Inspected element to find the domain and authorized that domain. Thanks!

@GurminderSingh If the answer solved your issue, You can accept the answer by clicking the checknark button on the left.
