Impossibility to load other views from homepage
I am trying to create a web app with google app script that has a home page and 3 buttons to load other views. I am able to deploy the app, the button works and the 3 other pages are able to load on their own. The issues occurs when I click on the hyperlinks using the button, the other pages do not load and I get the following error message : script.google.com does not authorises the connection (see screenshot)
I inspected the HTML page once loaded and the hyperlink in the button is ok (when I click on the link in the inspection page it works)
How could I solve the issue?
HTML for Homepage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title class = "center-align"> Hockey Player Manager</title>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section">
    <div class = "row">
    <div class ="input-field col s12">
      <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>?page=addplayer" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Ajouter un Joueur</a>
    </div>
    <div calss ="input-field col s12">
      <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>?page=removeplayer" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Enlever un Joueur</a>
    </div>
    <div class ="input-field col s12">
      <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>?page=createlineup"class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Créer une Compo</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


HTML for one of the other page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title class = "center-align"> Hockey Player Manager</title>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section">
    <h3 class="center-align">Ajouter un Joueur</h3>
    <!-- Add Player Form -->
    <div class="row" id="addPlayerForm">
          <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
            <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate" required>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
            <input id="lastName" type="text" class="validate" required>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
            <select id="positionDropdown" name = "positionDropdown" >
              <option value="" disabled selected>Selectionner une Position</option>
              <option value="Attaquant">Attaquant</option>
              <option value="Défenseur">Defenseur</option>
              <option value="Gardien">Gardien</option>
            </select>
            <label>Position</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" onclick="addPlayer()">Ajouter
              <i class="material-icons right">save</i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
            <div style="color: red" id="messageAddPlayer"></div>
            </button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
      // Function to add a player
    function addPlayer() {
      document.getElementById('messageAddPlayer').innerText = '';
      const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
      const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
      const position = document.getElementById('positionDropdown').value;

      if (!position || firstName =='' || lastName =='') {
        document.getElementById('messageAddPlayer').innerText = "Merci de remplir tous les champs";
        return;
      }

      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(message => {
          document.getElementById('messageAddPlayer').innerText = message;
        })
        .addPlayerFromWeb(firstName, lastName, position);

      document.getElementById('firstName').value = "";
      document.getElementById('lastName').value = "";
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });

  </script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

And the coge.gs
// Function to handle web app requests
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameter.page){
    var pageName = e.parameter.page.trim().toLowerCase();
    Logger.log(pageName);
    if (pageName !== "home"){
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(pageName);
      return template.evaluate();
    }else{
      return homePage();
    }
  }else{
    return homePage();
  }
}

function homePage(){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home");
  return template.evaluate();
}

Thanks a lot for your help
I tried with bonded and unbonded code and in both cases it does not work

target should be top. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-published-web-application-sidebar

Thanks, i added  in the head of my html and it works now

Redirect to web app to another page
Utilizing XFrameOptionsMode as discussed here worked for the situation on your code.
I modified your given code.gs and got it to redirect to another page
Modified Code
// Function to handle web app requests
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.page) {
    var pageName = e.parameter.page.trim().toLowerCase();
    Logger.log(pageName);
    if (pageName !== "home") {
      //I modified this section to use setFrameOptionsMode
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(pageName);
      return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    } else {
      return homePage();
    }
  } else {
    return homePage();
  }
}

function homePage() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home");
  return template.evaluate();
}

Sample Output

References:  XFrameOptionsMode 

There will be infinite nesting of frames with this method. Each anchor click  would deepen the iframe nest by 3 steps...( should be  apparent in Devtools F12)
